# Trying to make my select all/clear all button check and uncheck checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox, onclicklistener

I have a button that says `Select All`. When clicked all the `check boxes` in my `listview` should become checked. The same button changes text to `Clear All`. When clicked all the checkboxes should become unchecked and the text turns back to `Select All`....

In my `listview` however, it's every second button that becomes checked or unchecked.

When `Select All` is clicked, `checkbox 1`, `3` and `5` become checked. `Checkbox 2` and `4` become unchecked. text turns to `Clear All`.

When `Clear All` is clicked, `checkbox 1`, `3` and `5` become unchecked. `Checkbox 2` and `4` become checked. text turns to `Select All`.

I can't see what's wrong with my code. Or maybe it's something in another part of my app but there's no errors or warnings, not sure where to start debugging. Thanks.

```
   btnCheckAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count = MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) listView.getChildAt(i); // Find by under LinearLayout
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);


            if(btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select All")) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
                btnCheckAll.setText("Clear All");
            }


                else if (btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Clear All")){
                        checkbox.setChecked(false);
                btnCheckAll.setText("Select All");


            }}}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition inside the for loop keeps on Changing from `true` and `false` because the first loop changes the Text the second loop changes it again and it keeps on being changing in this part (*Read the comments!*):

```
if(btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select All")) {//This condition will be true on first round and 3 and 5 and 7...
            checkbox.setChecked(true);
            btnCheckAll.setText("Clear All");
        }


            else if (btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Clear All")){//And this one will be true in 2 and 4 and 6...
                    checkbox.setChecked(false);
            btnCheckAll.setText("Select All");
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
btnCheckAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean toCheck=true;

        //THE CONDITION SHOULD BE OUTSIDE THE LOOP!

 if(btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select All")) {
            toCheck=true;
            btnCheckAll.setText("Clear All");
        }


            else if (btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Clear All")){
                    toCheck=false;
            btnCheckAll.setText("Select All");


        }



        int count = MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) listView.getChildAt(i); // Find by under LinearLayout
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);
        checkbox.setChecked(toCheck);
    }}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be here:

```
if(btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select All")) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
                btnCheckAll.setText("Clear All");
}else if (btnCheckAll.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Clear All")){
                        checkbox.setChecked(false);
                btnCheckAll.setText("Select All");
}
```

This `if` is inside a loop, so it is acting as a swich turining on and off on each loop.

On each loop the text "Select All" / "Clear All" will change, so will do the evaluation of the button state in the next loop.